# How to print by print sectors

Tags: printing

I have an application in PHP is a system installed on Windows that was developed in Python. It is responsible for identifying a request that arrives in the php system that runs on the Web and automatically prints it on the default printer of the operating system.

I need to change this to print by sectors. Ex: Having a networked printer in the bar and another in the kitchen.
I need the drinks to be printed at the bar and food to be printed in the kitchen and the proof of delivery with the address and customer data on the USB printer.

Does anyone know how to do this?

......................